# To find multiple of a number that should contain only 9's and 0's

Tags: java, binary, numbers

You are given an integer N. Can you find the least positive integer X made up of only 9's and 0's, such that, X is a multiple of N?

I did solved this by taking each multiple of N and checking whether it contained only 9's and 0's. Realized off late that there is some way where Binary advantage can be taken. Not sure though. Can you help in telling me the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to systematically iterate the numbers consisting of 9's and 0's and check whether `N` is a factor.

Hint: a string of 9's and 0's can be encoded as a binary number, with each bit being 1 for a '9' and 0 for a '0'.

It is also possible that number theory (maths!) will offer some short cuts, but that is beyond the scope of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I propose you a simple algorithm to generate in increasing order the numbers consisting of 0's and 9's.

```
long[] series    = new long[1000];
series[1]        = 9;

int offset       = 1;
long base        = series[1];
int lastAllNines = 1;

for (int i=2 ; i<series.length ; i++) {
    if (offset == lastAllNines) {
        series[i]    = (series[i-1] + 1)*9;
        base         = series[i];
        offset       = 0;
        lastAllNines = i - 1;
    } else 
        series[i]    = base + series[1 + offset++];
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(series));
```

**Output :**

```
   [0, 9, 90, 99, 900, 909, 990, 999, 9000, 9009, 9090, 9099, 9900, 9909, 9990, 9999, 90000, 90009, 90090, 90099, 90900, 90909, 90990, 90999, ... ]
```

Comment: Umm - this is incorrect.  Where is `990` in the output?

Comment: Comment from **David T** that tried to edit my answer instead :  

*Looking at the output of this I notice a few numbers missing that I think should be there: 990 9090 9900 9909 9990 etc.

There seems to be some pattern to the missing numbers (lots of 90's), but I haven't delved into the code enough to see where the 'error' is. Of course I could be misunderstanding the output or something, but since this edit suggestion will get peer reviewed before it gets posted, then anyone feel free to override or correct me if I've missed something.*

Comment: @Dici - Actually, DON'T.  The OP asked for the logic ... not a solution.  The point is that he will learn more by working out the details for himself.

Comment: @StephenC I'll do it for myself, because I can see I have simplified a lot the problem. I'm missing all the `9*9*0*`

Comment: Last edit : optimized it by using the value of the offset instead of an `allNines` method to know when I should add a digit